# Merging website info into an array

Tags: php, array, screen-scraping, xpath

I'm scraping a title and a link from a website and placing them in a single array.
The `$i` variable seems a bit wrong to me, or is it perfectly fine?

```
$linkQuery = $xpath->query("//div[@class='news-archive']//a/@href");
$titleQuery = $xpath->query("//div[@class='news-archive']//a");

$data = [];

foreach ($linkQuery as $link) {
    $data[] = array('link' => $link->value);
}

$i = 0;
foreach ($titleQuery as $title) {
    $data[$i]['title'] = $title->nodeValue;
    $i++;
}
```

I do like the structure of the `Array`:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [link] => http://www.gpupdate.net/nl/f1-nieuws/321783/force-india-vreest-voor-deelname-aan-laatste-test/
            [title] => Force India vreest voor deelname aan laatste test
        )
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that one of the collections you iterate already has all the data you need. Try this:

```
$linkQuery = $xpath->query("//div[@class='news-archive']//a");
foreach ($linkQuery as $link) {
    $data[] = array('link' => $link->getAttribute('href'), 'title' => $link->nodeValue);
}
```

Btw. [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is another way for traversing two (or more) arrays simultaneously:

```
$group_elements = function($link, $title) {
    return array('link' => $link->value, 'title' => $title->nodeValue);
};
$data = array_map($group_elements, $linkQuery, $titleQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

The "i" is not necessary when you already have the array key.

The key applies to both link and title.

### PHP

```
$linkQuery = array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5");
$titleQuery = array("title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", "title5");



foreach($linkQuery as $k => $link){
  $data[$k] = array('link' => $link,'title' => $titleQuery[$k]);
}

.
```

### The Result

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'link1',
    'title' => 'title1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'link2',
    'title' => 'title2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'link3',
    'title' => 'title3',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'link4',
    'title' => 'title4',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'link5',
    'title' => 'title5',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

using two foreach loops seems redundant

```
<?php 

//I'm assuming this is the data that you'd recieve in a form of an object and that there are as many links as titles
$linkQuery = array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5");
$titleQuery = array("title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", "title5");

$data = array();

if(count($linkQuery) == count($titleQuery)){
    /*
     *if there are as many links as there are titles we start a 
     *for loop that goes through all titles and therefore links too
    */
    for ($i=0; $i < count($titleQuery); $i++) { 
        /*
         *push the link and title inside data array one by one, keep in mind you'd have to replace 
         * $linkQuery and $titleQuery with the values relevant to you
         * they would probaly be $linkQuery[$i]->value and $titleQuery[$i]->nodeValue
        */
        $data[] = array('link' => $linkQuery[$i], 'title' => $titleQuery[$i]);

    }

}

var_dump($data);
/*
returns

array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'link' => string 'link1' (length=5)
      'title' => string 'title1' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'link' => string 'link2' (length=5)
      'title' => string 'title2' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'link' => string 'link3' (length=5)
      'title' => string 'title3' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'link' => string 'link4' (length=5)
      'title' => string 'title4' (length=6)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'link' => string 'link5' (length=5)
      'title' => string 'title5' (length=6)


*/

 ?>
```